# Design Question for sending e-mail notifications

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a very basic question however the solution might be somewhat complex.

1. How are website devs sending out e-mails such as forgot password links, registration messages, and/or any other notifictions that need to be sent.
2. Are developers storing the messages in SQL server, a seperate class, XML??

I am using the Onion model and my SMTP Interface is in app.core however my base class for sending mail is located in infrastructure.backends. I dont't want my application services be dependant on backends, not sure if this is right wrong or me being OCD..

I am using Ninject as my IOC/DI.

Comment: Let me clarify, I am very well versed on the the System.Net.Mail namespace. My question was more of an architecture question I suppose. Sending e-mail is simple ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly modified from a post I found, this seems to be the right way to roll. At least it is a start.
 public interface IViewMailer
    {
        string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model, ControllerContext controllerContext);
    }

```
public class ViewMailer : IViewMailer
{
    #region IViewMailer Members

    public string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model, ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))

            viewName = controllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
        controllerContext.Controller.ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewEngineResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(controllerContext, viewEngineResult.View,
                                              controllerContext.Controller.ViewData,
                                              controllerContext.Controller.TempData, stringWriter);
            viewEngineResult.View.Render(viewContext, stringWriter);
            return stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [Postal](https://github.com/andrewdavey/postal) . I think it's the most efficient way of developing email templates. The architecture can be built keeping it in mind. It allows us to change the templates without re-compiling the code.

As per architecture, I haven't really had any issues with keeping it as part of my application services.

Comment: This looks interesting, it uses Views as templates.. Checking this out now.

Comment: +1 for Postal - i'm using it now, it rocks. So nice to write email in views rather than building up HTML in a string. never...again.

Answer (score 2):

If you're sending html emails, I use a slimmed down master/layout page and views. Then I let the controller render that view to a string for use in the emails. It's just like any other mvc view and model.

Comment: LOL. I was just about to say after thinking about it, Just render the damn view to a string and blast off... Way cool.

Answer (score 0):

In c# you System.Net.Mail.  I will do most things for you.

Comment: In fairness to this answer, the OP didn't add that comment regarding `System.Net.Mail` until after this answer was added.

Comment: ooh it let me fix ya... sry sir about anything negative.